# return boolean value higher up the chain in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in **jQuery**:

```
function vali(id) {
    $(id).bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText) {
        $(id).removeClass('validationError');
        if(errorFound) {
          $(id).addClass('validationError');
          return false;
        };
        return true;
    });
}
```

I am adding a validation class to inputs in a complex form to style it appropriately when an input is invalid. I would also like to return a true or false value based on this. The '`validationError`' class is being added correctly to inputs but I cannot return the boolean value as I suspect that I am calling a function within a function here and therefore need to return the value to the higher order function? Something like "`return.return false;`" Obviously this doesn't work but you get what I'm thinking on this. Maybe I am way off?

If I reference a specific input say for eg:

```
console.log( vali('#cause-name') );
```

the validationError styling works but I get 'undefined' in the console. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function vali(id) {
        var valid = true;
        $(id).bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText) {
            $(id).removeClass('validationError');
            if(errorFound) {
              $(id).addClass('validationError');
              valid = false;
            };
            valid = true;
        });
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: May be you have to remove valid = true; after the if